# como valido si una url de un servicio está en linea

Tags: nodejs, loopback

Lo que pasa es que voy a crear un desarrollo donde deseo monitorear si los servicios de algunos terceros se encuentran en línea o no

Ejemplo: tengo un endpoint https://apitercero/api/consultarPacientes GET.

Necesito validar que el servicio https://apitercero esté en linea.

Estuve validando con algunas librerias como https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-openapi-validator#configuration y no me funcionó.

Lo necesito es más para hacerle un seguimiento a los terceros y enviar correos si detecto anomalías del servicio y no tanto cuando se consume el endpoint

Ojalá me puedan ayudar

Comment: Que es lo que trataste, agregalo a tu pregunta, revisar [ask]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si las apis tienen login, programa tu servicio para iniciar sesión. Comprueba que en la respuesta se haya generado un token. Si eso esta integrado en el sistema, pues todo lo demás debería funcionar.

Comment: Tienes algún endpoint que puedas consultar periodicamente sin afectar nada? es decir por ejemplo un endpoint a "https://apitercero/api/" o a "https://apitercero/api/test" que te pueda indicar el estado de la api?
Porque no necesariamente si "https://apitercero/" funciona, significa que la api en "https://apitercero/api/" esté activa y funcionando. Si lo que quieres saber es si el servidor se cayó para "https://apitercero", quizas puedas hacer un HEAD o en su defecto un GET a / (si es que https://apitercero está bien hecha y retorna codigos http correctos